# Creating a Dog Class in Python

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first experience with python programming, and I am currently working on how to create a class. Below is my code:

```
class Dog():#Defining the class
    """A simple attempt to model a dog."""#Doc string describing the class

    def _init_(self, name, age):#Special method that Python runs automatically when a new instance is created. 
                             #Self must be the first variable in this function
        """Initialize name and age attributes."""
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def sit(self):
        """Simulate a dog sitting in response to a command."""
        print(self.name.title() + " is now sitting.")

    def roll_over(self):
        """Simulate rolling over in response to a command."""
        print(self.name.title() + " rolled over!")

my_dog = dog('willie', 6)#Telling python to create the dog named willie who is 6.

print("My dog's name is " + my_dog.name.title() + ".")#Accessing the value of the variable created
print("My dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")#Accessing the value of the 2nd variable
```

However, I get an error message when trying to build that states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dog.py", line 19, in <module>
    my_dog = dog('willie', 6)#Telling python to create the dog named willie who is 6.
NameError: name 'dog' is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `dog` is not `Dog`!

Comment: Also, `_init_` is not `__init__`.

Comment: Ah those small details. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues:

```
my_dog = Dog(name='willie', age=6) ## make sure the class name is capital
dog == Dog(******)
```

Also, your `__init__` needs two underscores:
`__init__` is correct,
`_init_` is not correct.

try with these modifications!

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved version:

```
class Dog: 
    'A simple dog model.'

    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        'Construct name and age attributes for an instance of Dog'
        self.name = name.title()
        self.age = age

    def sit(self):
        'Simulate a dog sitting in response to a command.'
        print(self.name + " is now sitting.")

    def roll_over(self):
        'Simulate rolling over in response to a command.'
        print(self.name + " rolled over!")

my_dog = Dog(name='willie', age=6)

print("My dog's name is " + my_dog.name + ".")
print("My dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")
```

Title case the name once when constructing an instance. That is an example of "Don't Repeat Yourself", aka the DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dog():
    """一次模拟小狗的简单尝试"""

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        """初始化属性name和age"""
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def sit(self):
        """模拟小狗被命令时坐下"""
        print(self.name.title() + " is now sitting.")

    def roll_over(self):
        """模拟小狗被命令时打滚"""
        print(self.name.title() + " rolled over!")

my_dog = Dog('White', 6)

print("My dog's name is " + my_dog.name.title() + ".")
print("My dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")
```

Maybe you used indentation to get `my_dog` into `Class Dog()` incorrectly.